# Check box when clicking on a row, not just the checkbox, in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have

```
<v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      item-key="userNumber"
      class="fixed-table-users"
      :search="search"
      hide-default-footer
      hide-default-header
      single-select
      :items="users"
      :headers="headers"
      disable-pagination
      show-select
    >
</v-data-table>
```

As of now I get a list with a checkbox to the left which is what I want, but I have to click the checkbox itself to mark the row. I would like to be able to click anywhere to select the row and check the box.

The most promising thing I have found in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events) is to use `@click:row` with the item and slot to manually set the box, doing something like this

```
<v-data-table
      ...
      :items="users"
      :headers="headers"
      disable-pagination
      show-select
      @click:row="(item, slot) => slot.isSelected = !slot.isSelected"
    >
</v-data-table>
```

But even though it is now selected if console loggin the `slot`, it is not shown in the UI.

How do I do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but you are selecting the row the wrong way. Instead of doing this `slot.isSelected = !slot.isSelected`. Do it like this:

```js
@click:row="(item, slot) => slot.select(!slot.isSelected)"

// You can also destructure the slot object

@click:row="(item, {select, isSelected}) => select(!isSelected)"
```

If you check `v-data-table` [API documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-click:row) you can see that the click:row event also comes with a helper function called `select`. This is the one that helps you selecting the row.
[image]

Comment: Ahh, yeah ofc "select" means "select", I feel stupid :p Thank you!